# New to SML and functional programming. Beginner questions

Tags: functional-programming, sml

I'm trying to define the logical operation *exclusive or* as a two-variable function. I can't use constants, type annotations or if-then-else. I believe I'm supposed to do it by using logic operators, but am lost on how I'm supposed to write out a function just using those! So far I have

```
fun xor(a,b) = a orelse b andalso not(a andalso b).
```

How am I supposed to return a true value from this point?

Answer (score 4):

First, so you don't need to remember the relative precedence and associativity of `andalso` and `orelse` I'd use more parens:

```
fun xor(a,b) = (a orelse b) andalso not(a andalso b);
- map xor [(true, true), (true, false), (false, true), (false, false)];
val it = [false,true,true,false] : bool list
```

Your error was that your expression associated as follows

```
a orelse (b andalso not(a andalso b));
```

There is no notion of 'returning' in sml.  There are only expressions, which are evaluated to values, which are in turn used in other expressions.

```
(a orelse b) andalso not(a andalso b)
```

evaluates to a value of type `bool`.  You can use that result in further computations:

```
if xor(foo, bor) then 1 else 2
```

Comment: Also, this can be implemented shorter: `fun xor (a, b) = a <> b`. The type of this funcion is `''a * ''a -> bool` - if you want it to be `bool * bool -> bool`, you must add a type constraint, which is a bit clumsy, but works: `fun xor (a : bool, b) = a <> b`